# Rails, duplicate models show on template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my template, I show books ordered by their child's created_at (reviews). But when I order it this way, the books are shown twice/thrice (varies). How can I resolve this?

My controller:

```rb
@pagy, @books = pagy_countless(Book.where(user_id: current_user.id).joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at DESC").group("books.id, comments.created_at"), items:10 )

# I am using pagy gem
```

As you can see, I've tried `group()`. Doesn't help. I've also tried adding `.distinct` to the end of the code (and in the middle). Doesn't help.

```rb
@pagy, @books = pagy_countless(Book.where(user_id: current_user.id).joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at DESC").distinct, items:10 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not using the pagy gem while you're debugging this. Add it back later when you've got a non-paged version working.

The `joins` will indeed produce multiple instances of `Book`. What you need is

```rb
@books = Book.where(user_id: current_user.id).includes(:comments)
```

Then in the template (you didn't show us, so I'm making assumptions":

```rb
<%- @books.each do |book| %>
  <h2><%= book.title %></h2>
  <ul>
  <%- book.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <li><%= comment.text %></li>
  <%- end %>
  </ul>
<%= end %>
```

(hope I got all the erb right there! I've been using haml for years!)

Comment: Thank you! This works. One issue is that the list now has empty first page, etc. because I'm omitting books that have no children (and doing this in view via <% if...). But that's a separate question and I'll post anew.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `select MAX` each group instead of`order DESC`

```rb
Book.joins(:comments)
 .select("books.*, MAX(comments.created_at) as c_max")
 .where(user_id: current_user.id)
 .group("books.id")
```