# How to omit parents that have no children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am omitting parents that have no children and doing this in the view:

```rb
 <% @books.each do |b| %>
 <% if b.comments.empty? %>
 <% else %>
.....
```

My controller:

```rb
@pagy, @books = pagy_countless(Book.where(user_id: current_user.id).includes(:comments).order("comments.created_at DESC").group("comments.created_at, books.id"), items:10 )
```

And I am using pagy gem.

The issue is that the first page of the pagination is empty, with all the parents and their children showing on the second page. This is because I am omitting childless parents from the view and there are enough such parents that come on top that the first page is entirely empty.

How can I omit childless parents from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is iterating over the collection, and not displaying the book if its comments are empty. This will indeed give you rows empty output, which is not what you want.

What you want is a query that will give you a collection containing only those books with comments.

Depending on how your associations are set up, you may be able to do this with a left outer join:

```rb
# books_controller.rb
def index
  @books = current_user.books.left_join(:comments).distinct(:id).where.not(comments: {id: nil})
  @pagy, @books = paginate(@books, items: 10)
end
```

This will generate SQL something like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "books".* FROM "books" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."member_id" = "books"."id" 
WHERE "books"."user_id" = $1 
AND "comments"."id" IS NOT NULL
LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3 [["user_id", "123"], ["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

Then, because your collection will only contain books with comments, you can simply render the whole collection:

```
<!-- books/index.html.erb -->
<= render collection: @books %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What's good about this is that it gets rid of the childless parents. But it gives duplicate parents. I had switched to ```includes(...)``` for this reason, but ```includes(...)``` shows childless parents. If you know another way to do this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: My question that led me to use ```includes```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605659/rails-duplicate-models-show-on-template/68612955#68612955

Comment: You are right, an inner join would give you dups on the books. Maybe you need a left join, combined with distinct, which should give you only unique books. I've updated the answer.

Comment: FYI this query is the opposite of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570221/155826

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I can't now order this by comment created date. I get this error: ```PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list LINE 1: ... "comments"."id" IS NOT NULL ORDER BY comm... ^```

Comment: I added this to the second line: ```.order("comments.created_at DESC")```. I deleted the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only fetch records with a match in the join table you want to use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
@books = Book.joins(:comments)
```

`.includes`, `.eager_load`, `.left_join` and `.preload` create an `OUTER JOIN`.

If you want to use an INNER JOIN yet avoid those pesky N+1 queries you can use `.joins` together with `.includes` or `.eager_load`:

```
@books = Book.joins(:comments)
             .includes(:comments)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, max. The issue here is actually that while ```@books = current_user.books.left_join(:comments).distinct(:id).where.not(comments: {id: nil})``` and ```@pagy, @books = paginate(@books, items: 10)``` shows distinct values, when I add ```.order("comments.created_at DESC")``` the error message shows: ```PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list LINE 1: ... "comments"."id" IS NOT NULL ORDER BY comm...```. If you know a solution, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: To clarify, this issue arose after implementing Ryan's solution, which partially solves my original issue (if not for the above error).